# alignment of label text in metapost

Tags: labels, metapost

I have a simple question.

```
label(btex AAA etex, (0,0)) ;
label(btex AAAAA BBBB CCCC etex,(0,-10));
```

The above statements gives center-alignment.
Then how can I make left or right alignment ?
I tried to search the manual with keyword "alignment" but surprisingly no result.
I can use \begin{minipage}[t]{20em}  ... \end{minipage} , but I want to go simpler way.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `label.lft` and `label.rt`?

Comment: Thank you. label.lft was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `label` takes an optional suffix that controls how the string or picture is placed relative to the location.  So

```
label.rt("AAA", (10,10));
```

will draw "AAA" in the default font with the left hand edge at `(10,10)` and

```
label.lft("BBB", (20,20));
```

will draw "BBB" with the *right hand* edge at `(20,20)`.

The other suffixes you have are: `urt`, `ulft`, `lrt`, `llft`, `bot`, and `top`.  If you omit the suffix, then `label` with draw the text centered as you have discovered.

You also have `dotlabel` which does exactly the same, except that it adds a dot at the location.

You can control the offset from the location to the reference point of the label with the internal parameter `labeloffset`.  And you can control the size of the dot drawn by `dotlabel` with the parameter `dotlabeldiam`.

If you want to do more fancy placement you can turn your string into a picture then use draw directly.  Like this

```
draw "AAA" infont "phvr8r" shifted 42 dir 30;
```

or perhaps

```
draw TEX("$A$") shifted 42 dir 30;
```

if you are using `lualatex` or you have done `input TEX`.

The alignment suffixes are explained in detail at the beginning of section 8 of the [Metapost manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/metapost/mpman.pdf), page 21 in the current edition.

Comment: Thank you again.  May be I am too much sterotyped.